# Changing standard property into a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

In developing some UserControls for internal use I followed this exmaple from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee712573(v=vs.100).aspx

The public value of one control is used by another control.  The way I have this working currently is hooking into an event that is fired in the first control through code-behind.  I am thinking that making one or both of the properties DependencyProperties which would eliminate the need for the code-behind.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private DataModel1 dm;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        this.DataContext = new DataModel1();
        dm = (DataModel1)DataContext;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public DataValue CurrentValue
    {
        get { return dm.CurrentValue; }
        set { dm.CurrentValue = value; }
    }
}
public class DataModel1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataValue _myData = new DataValue();
    public DataValue CurrentValue
    {
        get { return _myData; }
        set { if (_myData != value) {_myData = value OnPropertyChanged("CurrentValue"); }
    }
    // INotifyPropertyChanged Section....
}
```

The property is just a pass through from the `DataModel1` class.

Both UserControls are very similar in their structure and have the same public properties. I would like to replace the code behind eventhandler with a Binding similar, I think to:

```
<my:UserControl1 Name="UserControl1" />
<my:UserControl2 CurrentValue={Binding ElementName="UserControl1", Path="CurrentValue"} />
```

but the standard examples of DependencyProperties have getters and setter that use the `GetValue` and `SetValue` functions which use a generated backing object instead of allowing a pass through.

```
public DataValue CurrentValue
{
    get { return (DataValue)GetValue(CurrentValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentValueProperty, value); }
}
```

I think the DP should look like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentValueProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentValue", typeof(DataValue), typeof(UserControl1));
```

How can I change the definition of the public backing property to support the databinding pass through?

Answer (score 0):

I found that jumping into the OnPropertyChanged event allowed me to pass the data through to the `DataModel1`.  I am not 100% sure that this is the correct answer but it gets the job done.

Here is the corrected code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentValueProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentValue", typeof(DataValue), typeof(UserControl1),
       new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnCurrenValueChanged)));
private static void OnCurrentValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc = d as UserControl1;
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            uc.dm.CurrentValue = e.NewValue as DataValue;
        }
    }
public DataValue CurrentValue
{
        get { return GetValue(CurrentValueProperty) as DataValue; }
        set { SetValue(CurrentValueProperty, value); }
    }
```